# What is the best way to listen Amazon Kinesis Data Streams in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

So, I am playing with Kinesis Data Streams, and I am interested in how to get data from stream **efficiently**(Best practice for doing that)?

I have some considerations about this:

**1. Using AWS Lamba.**

Sounds good, but what if my consumer some instance, should I redirect lambda to my instance for getting some data? Seems noneffective...

**2. Using polling.**

As I understand, using polling isn't good idea, it produces overloads.

**3. [Async client from aws-sdk for Ruby](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-amazon-kinesis-subscribetoshard-api-support-in-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby/).**

**I've tried to check it**, but seems [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1218) has not http2. Getting an error: `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong version number (Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError)`. Did you try it with real AWS account?

So, for recap, I want to ask community about more efficient way to retrieve data from Kinesis Data Streams.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Denis! Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question sounds primarily opinion based, which is off topic for this site.  Be sure to check out this part of the help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and double check that this question fits the site topic.  Best of luck solving your problem.

Comment: Also you may want to clarify what you mean by "efficient", and provide more detail about what you've already tried.